# Adjusting Train/Test for training a model to a selected range with an expression

Tags: r

I have following vector and also in order to train a model I use the expression below - In the example below I want to have as test (FALSE) the last element of the train/test (TRUE/FALSE)

```
x<-c(1,2,3,2,1,4,3,2,3,1,3,4,3,2,1,3,4,5,5,6,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,9,1,8,6,4,5,2,3,1,1,5,4)

S<-runif(length (x))<= .90
while(S[length(S)] [!FALSE]) {S<-runif(length (x))<= .90}
train<-print(S)
```

I have two questions:

1. Why when I run 90% train (TRUE) / 10% test (FALSE) test I obtain a greater number of FALSE  than the 10% indicated as TEST and is there a way to make just 10% of FALSE only.
2. How could I frame the second part of the expression "while(S...)" for the FALSE to be consecutive (eg. - the (Test-FALSE) 10% are found only at the end of "train" instead than randomly distributed.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix ideas, in your example `length(x)` is 39. So,

```
S<-runif(length (x))<= .90
```

creates a vector of T/F, also of length 39, where ~90% of the values are `T`. Then the expression

```
S[length(S)] [!FALSE]
```

just extracts the last element of `S` (in an extremely convoluted way), and

```
while(S[length(S)] [!FALSE]) {S<-runif(length (x))<= .90}
```

creates a new vector `S` *until the last element is F*, when it stops. The final `S` is generated in exactly the same way as the initial `S`, so there will be about 10% `F`.

So basically your loop does nothing useful that I can discern.

If you want a random sample from x containing 90% of the values, you could do this:

```
s <- sample(1:length(x),0.9*length(x))
train <- x[s]
test  <- x[-s]
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand. The example was because I wanted the last element of train/test to be false. In the same way my second question was asking how to make all 10% of train to be at the end of the train/test not random